# Buttons changing differently with identical function

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

I am trying to make all buttons unilateral however the buttons defined at the beginning appear different despite being defined identical to buttons later on. Another issue I'm having is changing the colour of the title bar.

I've tried defining the original button "quit" later on but it still appears like that and the option buttons still appear like that. [shown later]

```
def createWidgets(self):
        self.question = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to Quiz App\nEach round we will ask you a question\nEach round you will have to\nchoose the correct answer\nGet it right and get a point\nGet it wrong and you don't.")
        self.question.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
        self.ocontinue = tk.Button(self, width=12)
        self.ocontinue["text"] = "Continue"
        self.ocontinue["command"] = self.ogcont
        self.ocontinue.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", width=8,fg="red", command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.grid(column=1, row=7, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.question.config(bg="#404040", fg="white")
        self.ocontinue.config(highlightbackground="#404040")
        self.QUIT.config(highlightbackground="#404040")
        root.config(bg="#404040")
 <~ the original configs
```

---

```
    def darkMode(self):
        self.answercheck.config(bg="#404040", fg="white")
        self.ocontinue.config(highlightbackground="#404040")
        self.option1.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.option2.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.option3.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
        self.option4.config(highlightbackground="#404040", highlightthickness=2)
<~ the configs applied to the option buttons.
```

[original configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fBCI.png)

[darkmode configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRxo5.png)

Comment: maybe create own widget `class MyButton(tk.Button)` with all colors and later use only this widget.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you clarify again? Do you wish to change the background color of certain buttons?